# Cocoa bindings and KVO, unregister the observer, when the observing object gets `dealloced`

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing, dealloc

**How can i unregister the observer, when the observing object gets `dealloced`?**

How can cocoa bindings handle a situation when the observed objects gets deallocated?

By using manual KVO, i have to remove the observing (removeObserver) before `dealloc` the object... how does Cocoa bindings handle this (stop observing on dealloc of the observed object)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 2017**

As @GregBrown has pointed out in the comments the original 2013 answer does not work in 2017. I *assume* the original answer did work in 2013, as my practice is not to answer without testing, but I no longer have any code I used.

So how do you do solve this in 2017? The simplest answer is swizzling, which some will find a contradiction but it need not be when using blocks. Below is a quick proof-of-concept with the following caveats:

- This is not thread safe. Consider what might happen if two or more threads execute the code at the same time. Standard techniques will address that.
- Efficiency was not a consideration! For example, you might wish to swizzle `dealloc` once per class and keep a list of observer/keypath in a per-instance associated object.
- This code *only* supports auto-removal, you cannot manually choose to remove an observer. You might wish to change that.

The code:

```
@implementation AutoRemovedKVO

typedef void (*DeallocImp)(id, SEL);

+ (void)forTarget:(NSObject *)target
      addObserver:(NSObject *)observer
       forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
          options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptions)options
          context:(nullable void *)context
{
   // register the observer
   [target addObserver:observer forKeyPath:keyPath options:options context:context];

   // swizzle dealloc to remove it

   Class targetClass = target.class;
   SEL deallocSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"dealloc");
   DeallocImp currentDealloc = (DeallocImp)method_getImplementation(  class_getInstanceMethod(targetClass, deallocSelector) );

   // don't capture target strongly in block or dealloc will never get called!
   __unsafe_unretained NSObject *targetPointer = target;

   void (^replacementBlock)(id self) = ^(__unsafe_unretained id self)
   {
      if (self == targetPointer)
         [targetPointer removeObserver:observer forKeyPath:keyPath];

      currentDealloc(self, deallocSelector);
   };

   class_replaceMethod(targetClass, deallocSelector, imp_implementationWithBlock(replacementBlock), "v@:");
}

@end
```

Both uses of `__unsafe_unretained` are to work around consequences of ARC. In particular methods usually retain their `self` argument, `dealloc` methods do not, and blocks follow the same retain-as-needed model. To use a block as the implementation of `dealloc` this behaviour needs to be overridden, which is what `__unsafe_unretained` is being used for.

To use the above code you simply replace:

```
[b addObserver:a forKeyPath:keyPath options:options context:NULL];
```

with:

```
[AutoRemovedKVO forTarget:b addObserver:a forKeyPath:keyPath options:options context:NULL];
```

Allowing for the above caveats the above code will do the job in 2017 (no guarantee for future years!)

**Original 2013 Answer**

Here in outline is how you can handle this, and similar situations.

First look up *associated objects*. In brief you can attach associated objects to any other object (using `objc_setAssociatedObject`) and specify that the associated object should be retained as long as the object it is attached to is around (using `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN`).

Using associated objects you can arrange for an observer to be automatically removed when the observed object is deallocated. Let X be the observer and Y be the observed objects.

Create an "unregister" class, say Z, which takes (via init) an X & Y and in its `dealloc` method does `removeObserver`.

To setup the observation, X:

1. Creates an instance of Z, passing itself and Y.
2. Registers itself as an observer of Y.
3. Associates Z with Y.

Now when Y is deallocated Z will be deallocated, which will result in Z's `dealloc` being called and unregistering the observation of X.

If you need to remove the observation of X while Y is still active you do this by removing the associated object - and doing so will trigger its `dealloc`...

You can use this pattern whenever you want to trigger something when another object is deallocated.

HTH

Comment: So basically i create an object Z, which lifetime is bound to Y lifetime (only Y holds strong to Z), but Z is also keeping a weak reference to X... thus when Y gets dealloced, Z gets dealloced as well, causing Z to trigger remove observing of X from Y... right?

Comment: That sounds right... Think of it as attaching an additional "dealloc" method to another object, what that method does when it is called is up to you.

Comment: just curious, what do you thing about the method observing self.dealloced?

Comment: @PeterLapisu - With a cursory glance only: the obvious difference is using associated objects does not require modification of the observed object, while having objects provide a property which can be observed obviously does and so may not always be (easily) possible. Pick which suits.

Comment: In theory this sounds like a great idea, but has anyone actually verified that this works in practice? From what I've seen in my own code, Y is deallocated before its associated objects are, which results in an exception because the observers have not yet been removed.

Comment: @GregBrown - Hmm, back in 2013 I would have tested this before posting, but today in 2017 you are correct and it is not working as described. I can't think of anything I knew back then that I forgot to put in the answer. So you'll need to swizzle the dealloc method and use the associated object to store the observers & key paths. Your swizzled dealloc first unregisters the observers and then invokes the original dealloc. (Swizzling is of course how KVO itself works.)

Comment: That's pretty much the same conclusion I came to. I was hoping to avoid swizzling, though...I wonder if maybe in your original example you weren't using ARC? I think it may have worked as described using manual memory management.

Comment: @GregBrown - Swizzling doesn't need to be too horrendous, I've added an update to the answer.

Comment: @CRD - Thanks for the update! I like the block approach.

Answer (score 1):

From the KVO guide (emphasis mine): The key-value observing `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` method does not maintain strong references to the observing object, the observed objects, or the context. **You should ensure that you maintain strong references to the observing, and observed, objects, and the context as necessary**.

Cocoa Bindings manage the strong references during `bind:` and `unbind:`.

To answer your question "How can i unregister the observer, when the observing object gets dealloced?": **You don't unregister the observer, because the observer should maintain a strong reference to the observed object. Thus the observed object doesn't get deallocated.**

Another way to think of this, you are observing properties, *but not the observed object itself*. So you only care when properties are set to nil. Because you are maintaining a strong reference as an observer, the observed object will not be deallocated until the observing object is done observing it.

So if the observed object was removed as a property you are observing *of another object*, that would cause you to stop observing it (releasing the strong reference) and then allow the observed object to be deallocated. That property you are observing may be a collection of objects, so you would observe the object being removed, causing you to stop observing and allowing the object to dealloc.

Comment: and what in case a child is observing a parent object, those cannot hold a strong reference to it?

Comment: The child can hold a strong reference to the parent object. It's only going to cause a retain cycle if the child doesn't release the reference to the parent when it is removed as a child of the parent.

Comment: ok, but when the relationship wont't be removed and should be removed in dealloc (but dealloc gets never called cause of ARC cycle)?

Comment: If you want the child object to go out of scope (not delete the relationship as a child of parent), you unbind the child first. This decrements the parent reference allowing it to go out of scope when appropriate. Deleting the relationship is a different operation from object going out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

My patter that i tried and looks to work : X wants to observe Y

1) In Y declare a property

```
@property (assign) id dealloced;
```

2) In Y's dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc {
   self.dealloced = self;
}
```

3) In X observe also Y's keyPath dealloced

```
[Y addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dealloced" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:NULL];
```

4) In X just handle the KVO change for dealloced and unregister all observing

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    ...
    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"dealloced"]) {
       id obj = change[@"new"];
       [obj removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dealloced"];
       // remove other observing as well
    }
    ...
}
```

**And in X we don't even need to hold a reference to Y**

Comment: will this work?  Wont `obj` be deallocated by the time you get the KVO observeValueForKeyPath for realloced property.  I.e will `[obj removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dealloced"];` work at this point?